# Removing failed changes from Entity Framework context

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

### Scenario

- Ideally using DI ([Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/)) to manage contexts/repositories in scope, but in reality limited to a service-locator pattern, don't ask.  Ideal example:

  ```
  // EF code-first context
  kernel.Bind<MyDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope().WithConstructorArgument("connectionString",...);

  // EF code-first repositories
  kernel.Bind<IRepository<SomeModel>>().To<EfRepository<SomeModel, MyDbContext>>().InRequestScope();
  kernel.Bind<IRepository<AuditLog>>().To<EfRepository<AuditLog, MyDbContext>>().InRequestScope();
  ```
- In my service call, I attempt to save bad data to the database, so the repo/context `.SaveChanges()` correctly fails:

  ```
  try {
      var model = new SomeModel { Name = ..., Blah = ... }
      repoSomeModels.Add(model);
      repoSomeModels.Commit(); // bad data, throws exception
  }
  ```
- I then want to log a record of this failed attempt to the same database:

  ```
  catch(Exception ex) {
      repoAuditLogs.Add(new AuditLog { Action = ..., Result = ex.Message });
      repoAuditLogs.Commit();
      throw ex; // rethrow the problem so we can properly bail
  }
  ```

But, when attempting to save the changes in the second commit (`repoAuditLogs.Commit()`) I get the same exception again.  This is because the "bad data" from the first attempted commit is still sitting around in the EF Context, even though the attempt failed, and so EF tries again to commit the bad data, not knowing it shouldn't.

### Question

How do you remove failed changes from the the EF context?  Or am I going about this wrong?

*(Update: don't concentrate on the specifics of my scenario, i.e. because I'm effectively logging an error it might be appropriate to use a different context, but let's say I just want to do something else)*

### Possible Solutions

I came across this blog post -- http://rundevrun.blogspot.com/2012/06/entity-framework-removing-failed.html -- which says you should find all the problem entities and mark their changes as "accepted", which results in EF "ignoring" them during subsequent commits.  This works in my case, allowing me to save my audit log and "quit".

However, a colleague pointed out that this results in a context no longer correctly in sync with the data it represents, and thus is a terrible idea -- even though it's "okay" for my case (because I'm immediately stopping the program) if you were to continue the request (as suggested by the original post) you would run the risk of attempting to use a "corrupted" context, and you could get unintended side effects.

In another scenario to resolve deadlocks, he explicit wrapped the commit in a (code-based) transaction (EF already does this in SQL) so he could reattempt it, but this doesn't address my problem where the *data* is bad, not the *connection*.

The only other solution I can think of is to save my audits in a new context.  Ideally, I use DI/locator to map my audit repo to a different context, something like (emphasis `new MyDbContext` or whatever it should be):

```
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<AuditLog>>().To<EfRepository<AuditLog, MyDbContext>>(new MyDbContext(...)).InRequestScope();
```

but then I have two contexts floating around, which seems contrary to the point of sharing a context in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

Once `SaveChanges()` has failed your `Context` should be disposed as it is no good for any further activity.

Personally I use a separate object/context to log errors to the database and this error handling object with it's associated new `Context` instance is injected into exception handling decorators that wrap my services. The error logging object will also write to the error log if it fails to log to the database.

Exceptions are just that, exceptions, and so having two `Contexts` at this time is not a problem as it should not occur very often.

Comment: Yeah that's the conclusion I'm reaching _in my case (with error logging)_, but what about in a general sense?  Say I want to continue doing stuff after a bad attempt?  The statement >>> "Context should be disposed as it is no good for further activity" is interesting though -- is this how the `Context` is intended?  Then why do so many people suggest maintaining a single context rather than spinning one up and disposing it each time?  Maybe that's the real question...

Comment: @drzaus It's my understanding that the `Context` should be as short lived as possible. The `Context` is effectively a snapshot of data from the database, as the database moves on and the `Context` becomes *stale*. Keeping a single `Context` is only really applicable for single user database applications.

Comment: Keeping a single `Context` appears to be applicable in every example of IOC/DI ([Ninject repository](https://www.google.com/search?q=ninject+repository)) that I've seen, which may be part of my confusion.  At least with the `InRequestScope` it behaves as a "single user database application".

Comment: @drzaus see this link which I quote "For web applications you can use `InRequestScope()` to have `Ninject` create a single instance **for each request handled by your application**" - note the bold - "for each request" equates to a single short lived instance that is passed into all of the objects instantiated **per web request**. This should not be confused with `InSingletonScope()` which is one instance per `AppDomain`, i.e. a *singleton* https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.Common/wiki/InRequestScope

Comment: Sorry, am I not saying the same thing?  Using `InRequestScope`, being per web request, means that effectively the app only sees one user at a time, right?  If so, then using a single `Context` becomes applicable per your definition...

Comment: Probably we are talking along similar lines. It's perfectly ok to have multiple `Context` instances per request. It would seem *questionable* to have 2 of the **same** `Context` which is maybe where your question sits - what I’m talking about here are **Bounded `Contexts`** and/or a `UnitOfWork`. If one `UnitOfWork` fails you fire up a separate `UnitOfWork` to  log the errors etc.